# Scroll visibility

Tags: javascript, html, css

In css, i set the overlow property of the div to scroll and it works well. But the scrolls are visible but not active with a greyed color even they are not needed.

So how can i make the scrolls invisible when they are not needed ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That is the nature of `overflow: scroll`. Try `overflow: auto` instead.

Comment: overflow:auto didn't solver my problem because of the another issues. Is there any function to make scroll invisible?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use overflow-x and overflow-y css attributes to control autoscrolling of particular dimension of html element